# maven - skip dependency during build

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

I want to skip demo-api (Which is another module) during build. Setting optional true doesn't work. Any suggestions on how to skip it but not delete the dependency from pom.xml?

```
Failed to execute goal on project [36mdemo-web[m: [1;31mCould not resolve dependencies for project demo-web:demo-web:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies at demo-api:demo-api:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT[m: Failed to read artifact descriptor for demo-api:demo-api:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact demo-spring-boot:demo-spring-boot:pom:1.0-SNAPSHOT

    <dependency>
        <artifactId>demo-api</artifactId>
        <groupId>demo-api</groupId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Why not to comment it? What issue are you trying to address?

Comment: I don't want to comment it. Is there a tag that  can be provided to skip during the build? I don't want dev to comment and uncomment everytime

Comment: I cannot really follow you. If `demo-api` is a dependency of your project, you surely use it somewhere in the code? So leaving it out leads to compile errors?

Comment: Is this dependency only used during runtime? If so you could define `<scope>runetime<scope>` runtime (see details: https://maven.apache.org/pom.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can put that dependency in a profile:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.foo</groupId>
    <artifactId>foo</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <organization>
        <name>Example Company</name>
        <url>http://www.example.com/</url>
    </organization>

    <name>foo</name>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>includeBadDependency</id>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <artifactId>demo-api</artifactId>
                    <groupId>demo-api</groupId>
                    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

<!--    Normal dependencies go here-->
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.5.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

When you build this project:

```
$ mvn verify # this will succeed

$ mvn verify -PincludeBadDependency
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ----------------------------< org.foo:foo >-----------------------------
[INFO] Building foo 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
Downloading from maven-atlassian-com: https://packages.atlassian.com/maven/repository/internal/demo-api/demo-api/1.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading from maven-atlassian-com: https://packages.atlassian.com/maven/repository/internal/demo-api/demo-api/1.0-SNAPSHOT/demo-api-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
[WARNING] The POM for demo-api:demo-api:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
Downloading from maven-atlassian-com: https://packages.atlassian.com/maven/repository/internal/demo-api/demo-api/1.0-SNAPSHOT/demo-api-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  5.434 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-09-21T18:24:24+10:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project foo: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.foo:foo:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact demo-api:demo-api:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT in maven-atlassian-com (https://packages.atlassian.com/maven/repository/internal) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

Answer (score 0):

https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html

Maybe this can give you a hint or two.

```
<scope>runtime</scope>
```

I think this will do the trick